# How to make an async function call in Flutter without onPressed?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

This is probably a beginner question, but I want to assign a class variable the await of a Future function. I only know that you can use async functions in onPressed on buttons, but how can I run these at Widget build or even in initialization?

Comment: You can use async functions whereever you want. I suggest working on the fundamentals of the framework and Dart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you're trying to build a Widget that depends on a `future`, you may want to use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) Widget.

The `FutureBuilder` has its own build method, to which you can provide an initial value for the result of the `future` if you like.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: name_Of_Your_Future
        initialData: value, //initial value for the future(ie: until it resolves)
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
         
          //...some UI building logic here...
   
          //snapshot.data contains the result of your future,
          //once it is resolved

  }
}
```